# Refactoring a LINQ query that (sometimes) returns null

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following `LINQ` query that should return a result for each `Request`. I'd prefer to have the query translated to `SQL` by `EntityFramework`.

```
private static Expression<Func<Request, RequestResultModel>> requestResultExpression = request =>
    request.Applicant
            .ApplicantAddresses
            .OrderBy(address => address.IsPreferred)
            .Select(address => new RequestResultModel
            {
                Id = request.Id,
                ApplicantName = request.Applicant.FullName,
                ReviewerName = request.Reviewer.FullName,
                RefferrerName = request.Refferrer.Name,
                City = address.Address.City,
                Province = address.Address.Province.Code,
                DisciplineCode = request.Discipline.Code,
                Event = request.Event,
                StatusName = request.Status.Name,
                Submitted = request.Submitted
            })
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

The problem is that when the `Applicant` has no `ApplicantAddresses`, then the expression returns null for that specific `Request`. The correct behavior should be that a `RequestResultModel` should still be returned but with empty address information.

Unfortunately, I can only think of doing this in two steps like this:

```
private static Expression<Func<Request, RequestResultModel>> requestResultExpression = request =>
{
    var address = request.Applicant
                         .ApplicantAddresses
                         .OrderBy(address => address.IsPreferred)
                         .FirstOrDefault();

    return new RequestResultModel
            {
                Id = request.Id,
                ApplicantName = request.Applicant.FullName,
                ReviewerName = request.Reviewer.FullName,
                RefferrerName = request.Refferrer.Name,
                City = address == null ? null : address.Address.City,
                Province = address == null ? null : address.Address.Province.Code,
                DisciplineCode = request.Discipline.Code,
                Event = request.Event,
                StatusName = request.Status.Name,
                Submitted = request.Submitted
            };
});
```

Which has he following drawbacks:

1. It will not be translated to `SQL` by `EntityFramework`
2. It will be executed as multiple queries to the database

Any ideas how I can achieve the desired result?

All assistance will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Here is the `Request` class

```
public class Request
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Applicant Applicant { get; set; }

    public virtual Reviewer Reviewer { get; set; }

    public virtual Refferrer Refferrer { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Discipline Discipline {get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Event { get; set; }

    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }

    public DateTime Submitted { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [`.DefaultIfEmpty()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5538637/1188513) to make a LEFT JOIN instead of the INNER JOIN you're getting with your current code?

Comment: Listing the `Request` class could be pretty helpful..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your current code generates an INNER JOIN, which as you've noticed, excludes any `Applicant` without an `ApplicantAddress`.

You want to select from `Applicant` and generate a LEFT JOIN on `ApplicantAddress`, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5538637/1188513) shows how to use `DefaultIfEmpty()` to do that:

> ```
> var query = from u in usergroups
>             join p in UsergroupPrices on u equals p.UsergroupID into gj
>             from x in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
>             select new { 
>                 UsergroupID = u.UsergroupID,
>                 UsergroupName = u.UsergroupName,
>                 Price = (x == null ? String.Empty : x.Price) 
>             };
> ```

It's hard to tell exactly what/how to change in your code to make it work, because we're not seeing the `DbContext` and it's not clear how `Request` turns out hitting the database; I'd rather not say anything than assume what's going on.

In this specific case:

```
private static Expression<Func<Request, RequestResultModel>> requestResultExpression = request =>
    request.Applicant
            .ApplicantAddresses
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
            .OrderBy(address => address.IsPreferred)
            .Select(address => new RequestResultModel
            {
                Id = request.Id,
                ApplicantName = request.Applicant.FullName,
                ReviewerName = request.Reviewer.FullName,
                RefferrerName = request.Refferrer.Name,
                City = address.Address.City,
                Province = address.Address.Province.Code,
                DisciplineCode = request.Discipline.Code,
                Event = request.Event,
                StatusName = request.Status.Name,
                Submitted = request.Submitted
            })
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Your suggestion to use `DefaultIfEmpty()` is what worked. Mind updating the answer (for the benefit of others)?

Comment: @adaptive Cool, edited. Feel free to stick around and spend some of your votes - we need more [voters](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=week) on this site :)